# FirebaseFirestore security rules for map inside array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am creating a map inside array in firestore document I saw documentation for maps security rules and array security rules but not able to find for map inside array in firestore
[image]

Security rules for writing document

Comment: Can you show us what rules you habe until now and what do you want them to do at all? Is there a reason you use an array for such data?

Comment: the reason is I want to add those three fields in a array each time a user write and its just simple for write allow write: request.resource.data.reports??

Comment: When it's easy why do you need to ask questions about it? I think it would be easier by using a subcollection. I still don't get what your problem is :( Can you pls explain it a little bit more.

Comment: how I can verify fields of map like is String inside array list is the question like we do request.resource.data.details.name is for map ,request.resource.data.details[uid] is for array, how i can perform with map inside array list

Comment: I still don't get it :( but you can't perform a `map` inside the database rules.

Comment: I think we can by ex-detail.name